# Eliminating ambiguity by left factoring

Tags: parsing, ambiguity, compiler-theory

Can you eliminate ambiguity by left factoring?

For example, the dangling else.

Or is left factoring only eliminating left recursion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what left factoring usually refers to.

Example:

Before

```
G = "IF" cond "THEN" statements
    | "IF" cond "THEN" statements "ELSE" statements
...
```

After

```
G  = "IF" condition "THEN" statements G'
G' = "ELSE" statements
     | Εpsilon
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the dangling else, ambiguity is not eliminated by left factoring. You will still have two parse trees for nested if statements.